# I forgot what my subversion working directory is set to

Tags: svn, repository

I am trying to checkout some files from an svn repo using the svn checkout command, and I get the error

```
svn: 'path/to/mylocal/directory' is not a working copy
```

I don't know what the actual working copy is because I set it a while back I guess. Anyways, is there a way to resolve this issue? I need my local directory to be set to this repo.

Comment: `svn checkout` creates a working copy; it doesn't expect to find one at the target path, and in fact probably throws an error if it does. What exact command are you running?

Comment: In subversion, you cannot check out files, only directories. What command did you run to get that error message? Were you trying to get specific files from the repository into a local directory somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the svn ls XXXXXXX to navigate the svn filesystem and find the path you are looking for.  The first bit might be a bit tricky to find though - if you don't know it you would need to look at the SVN server config.